# Get all bus lines for a set of stops in overpass / OSM

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, osm2pgsql

I am trying to get a list of lines for a large set of busstops (lets assume to query worldwide). As far as I have figured it out, I get a set of busstops from [download.osmdata.xyz](http://download.osmdata.xyz/).
Now I could query overpass API with the OSM Node Ids like:

```
(node(483556383);
<;
);
(node(2101949781);
 <;
);
out;
```

How is the correct query if I am just interested in the relations pf type

```
<tag k="route" v="bus"/>
```

Or even better just get the line numbers at the set of bus stops.